# How does peanut pollination work?

Tags: botany, fruit, pollination

I got curious about peanuts and when I found some photos on the internet, I could see they have flowers. However peanut fruit is underground.

How does pollination of peanut flowers affect the fruit underground? Or are there two kinds of fruit, one from flower and one from the underground?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut

Comment: @John Where exactly is the explanation? Do you really think I didn't check wikipedia before asking?

Comment: Under the heading botany, it explains the entire process.